# how to change spring cloud config server url pattern to have path inside

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am using spring cloud config server to save all the configuration in various environments,upto now, it worked great, but now, I suddenly met an issue, don't knwo how to change it.

By default, the url pattern is: http://xxx.xx.xx:8888/{appName}/{environemnt}

But now I need to deploy multiple service together, and I can no longer use path to the root, and I need to use this one:

http://xxx.xxx.xx/pathToConfig/{appName}/{env}

But I noticed that spring config server will consider  as appName instead there.

May I ask if there are any configuration I can change to make sure spring config server be able to consider url only after some path after the root?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share your server and client properties? There is a property spring.cloud.config.server.prefix, that defines the location of served resources, but I can't be sure if it will work not seeing your configuration.

Comment: Could you use Spring profiles?

Answer (score 4):

`spring.cloud.config.server.prefix: /<path>` only changes the prefix for the config server api, not the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `server.contextPath: /pathToConfig` in your application.yml of other configuration.

Then it will prefix all the mappings with the specified path.